# Facebook Contacts disappearing from contacts

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, facebook

I am using the iOS Facebook Integration, which adds my Facebook friends to my contacts in the phone app.
Yesterday I noticed that some of these Facebook contacts have been disappeared, despite being still 'Friends' with them on Facebook.

Is this maybe due to some Facebook privacy feature?

Comment: Have the same issue. All of a sudden the number of contacts has decreased dramatically in my address book.

Comment: Some Problem: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5075700

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Facebook did this on purpose. Facebook tries to only sync contacts which include `useful information`.

Friends without contact information other than a '@facebook.com'-email are no longer synced.

[[Source]](http://9to5mac.com/2013/06/06/facebook-aims-to-declutter-the-ios-contacts-app-by-no-longer-syncing-friends-without-useful-contact-info/)